# Why does this object need a DataContext?

Tags: linq-to-sql

This is weird.

```
regiao C = new regiao();
C.Nome = textBoxNome.Text;
C.Descricao = textBoxDescicao.Text;
C.cidades.AddRange(ListaIN);
mgrRegiao mgr = new mgrRegiao();
mgr.UpdateRegiao(C);
```

C is a Linq object (code generated by VS2008 in the dbml file) the operation is out of any context. ListaIN in is of type List. That is also the type of C.cidades. The call to mgr.UpdateRegiao creates a context, Copies the contents to objects inside the context and updates the objects. Some of the itens in ListN may have come from a Context (from a query result)

When 
    C.cidades.AddRange(ListaIN)

Executes I get an exception

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'.
```

at the line

```
regiao previousValue = this._regiao.Entity;
```

in the generated code for the entity regiao set opeation.

```
[Association(Name="regiao_cidade", Storage="_regiao", ThisKey="IDRegiao",      IsForeignKey=true)]
    public regiao regiao
    {
        get
        {
            return this._regiao.Entity;
        }
        set
        {
            regiao previousValue = this._regiao.Entity;
            if (((previousValue != value) 
                        || (this._regiao.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
            {
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                if ((previousValue != null))
                {
                    this._regiao.Entity = null;
                    previousValue.cidades.Remove(this)
```

...

Whats wrong ? The object C does not have and never had a context. Why it needs a context and how do I solve this ? Is it because some itens in ListaIN came from the database ? If so, is there a way to detach them ?

Comment: Further testing showed that trying to add a item item to the C.cidades list gets the same error, even if the item mas created outside of a context.

Comment: OK. So you cannot mix objects from 2 different contexts or objects that have a context and objects that do not. So, I need a way to detach the objects that works with the code generated in the dbml file.

Comment: The data context that is creating the problem is the one from the objects in ListaIN. Why do objects that no longer have a valid context keep this information. Its not like you gonna recover any lazy initialized objects. Anyway, I was able to "detach" the objects and add them to the C.cidades list one by one. Doing C.cidades.AddRange(ListaIN) still generates an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so that just the way Linq is, i guess.